# Is there a 'contiguous' option for the magic wand in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

In Photoshop the *Magic Wand* tool has a *contiguous* setting, that when enabled, will cause the *Magic Wand* to select only one area. If disabled you will end up with several areas of the same color (depending on picture and settings of course).

Here's a picture to illustrate what I fail to explain:

[image]

Can I do this in Gimp?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes you can.

In Gimp you have two tools:

### The Fuzzy Select Tool

[image]
Which will allow you to choose an area based on the color and the similarity using a few additional tools like thresholding, mode, selection by composite, channel, saturation and value and a few more.

In the next example I am using the **Fuzzy Select Tool** which is selecting only the white color around the logo.

[image]

Using the same tool, I am adding inner sections of the logo by keeping the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key pressed while clicking on the sections to add.

[image]

### The Select by Color Tool

[image]
With this tool you can choose which color base regions you wish to choose with just a click, using additional tools, like: mode, selection by composite, channel, saturation and value and a few more.

In the next screenshot I am using the **Select by Color tool** in order to click into the center oval of the number nine in the logo in order to choose all the regions that are similar (based on the threshold) to the color I picked when clicking.

As in the previous tool, you can keep the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key pressed while clicking in order to continue adding adjacent areas.

[image]

Based on thresholding, the selection may be more accurate.

Depending on the mode that you use, you can have the effect that you wish. In the next example I have activated the second mode which will act as additive in both the Fuzzy and Color selection tools.

[image]

Comment: DoR: Thank you for the edit, I have transparent windows using compiz and some times (like this) the screenshots or partial screenshots shows part of my stuff in the desktop. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I think neither can be restricted to select only contiguous areas (unlike the "Foreground Select Tool").

Comment: @haridsv - No, as stated in this answer, the "fuzzy select" tool *does* select a contiguous area (always). Indeed, that's the (main) difference between it and "select by color". if "fuzzy select" is selecting more than you expect, lower the threshold. Be sure "Diagonal neighbors" is *not* checked. Make sure you are selecting in the layer you intended to.