# How does GImp compare to Photoshop?

Tags: graphics, gimp

Please be specific (apart from the obvious, eg. free and open source vs commercial support). I need this information in order to be certain as to what to expect and what not to expect from Gimp.

Comment: Both the Gimp and Photoshop are very complex pieces of software. Could you be more specific about what part or functions you would like to be compared otherwise any answer would have to be generic and basic at best

Comment: OK, it would be helpful just a general comparison of the main points at least. Also I have in mind the latest editions of both softwares.

Answer (score 4):

To the date I have asked to several friends about their usage in photoshop and what they couldn't find in Gimp, all they seems to be used to photoshop and feel comfortable with it but nobody could yet say anything that they would like Gimp to do and it can't.

I think that people is used to their respective tools and they don't want to abandon their "comfort point" in order to learn new things.

I think that the only thing you will have problems with, it will be the GUI. Gimp is featuring somehow a weird GUI but with a little of patience you will get used to it.

Another thing to be considered is that people is more used to the MS style software. Which makes people to lose time trying to do the things "as they know", instead of opening their minds to learning.

I don't think you are going to miss something of Photoshop if you are mind opened to learning, but even if you do, you can install it via PlayOnLinux. Take a look at [this previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28108/is-there-a-contiguous-option-for-the-magic-wand-in-gimp) and see that there are people using both Gimp and Photoshop and finding both are useful enough to give a chance.

### This is the Gimp:

[image]

### This is Photoshop (running under PlayOnLinux)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found on the web some Gimp limitations that I think are worth notice:

- No 16-bit support
- No CMY*K
- No non-destructive edit
- No Adjustment Layers
- No layer directories
- Limited Hue/Sat adjustment (only 6 colors to choose from with no feather)

Please tell me if any of these aren't valid anymore.

On the other hand I didn't find Photoshop important limitations over Gimp; well I didn't look much since I was more interested in limitations I'm going to face if I switch to Gimp.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added this to your question (by editing it).   People will look at your original question before noticing the information you've added here.

Comment: This are more concrete issues than can be discussed, and maybe the question would turn to be how to workaround this limitations (even whether they really are such) in Gimp.